# Azure SQL STRING_AGG as part of larger Query

Tags: sql-server, azure, many-to-many, concatenation

Many questions/solutions I've read here describe how to use STRING_AGG by itself and I can get the following to work:

```
SELECT Offers.Id, STRING_AGG ( Offers2Currencies.CurrencyCode, ', ' ) AS Currencies

FROM  Offers  INNER JOIN Offers2Currencies ON Offers2Currencies.OfferID = 
dbo.Offers.ID

WHERE dbo.Offers.BuyerMemberId = '64ad10b9-85a6-4fc4-b9eb-d9f9af164d2b'

GROUP BY    dbo.Offers.Id
```

But I am struggling with how to put that inside a larger query such as:

```
SELECT
    dbo.Offers.ID,
    dbo.Offers.UTC,
    dbo.Organizations.Code,
    dbo.Entities.EntityAbbrev,
    dbo.Measurables.Name,
    dbo.Offers.Price,
    dbo.Offers.SellerMemberId,
    dbo.AspNetUsers.UserName
    --select STRING_AGG(dbo.Offers2Currencies.CurrencyCode, ', ') Currencies

FROM    dbo.Offers
  INNER JOIN dbo.AspNetUsers ON dbo.AspNetUsers.Id = dbo.Offers.SellerMemberId
  INNER JOIN dbo.MemberCreditRatings ON dbo.AspNetUsers.Id = dbo.MemberCreditRatings.MemberGUID
  INNER JOIN dbo.Measurables ON dbo.Offers.MeasurableID = dbo.Measurables.ID
  INNER JOIN dbo.Entities ON dbo.Offers.EntityID = dbo.Entities.ID
  INNER JOIN dbo.Organizations ON dbo.Measurables.OrganizationID = dbo.Organizations.ID
  --INNER JOIN dbo.Offers2Currencies ON dbo.Offers2Currencies.OfferID = dbo.Offers.ID
  AND dbo.Entities.OrganizationID = dbo.Organizations.ID

WHERE   dbo.Offers.BuyerMemberId = '64ad10b9-85a6-4fc4-b9eb-d9f9af164d2b'
```

Comment: `cross apply`? Please provide some samples that would show what is causing difficulties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I (think) I figured it out -- put all fields being selected into the Group By (though they never get accessed beyond the first group by) -- see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/aaa65/7  (and advise if better or alternative solution)